# laravel blade include error - syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 4 locally with EasyPHP 14.1.
I have created a route :

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    return View::make('test');
});
```

a layout (testlayout.blade.php) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('container')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and a view (test.blade.php) :

```
@extends("testlayout")
@section('container')
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
@stop
```

It works fine and I get "Hello!"

But when a change my layout by adding an include like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @yield('container')
    </div>
        @include('testfooter')
</body>
</html>
```

with my footer (testfooter.blade.php) :

```
@section("testfooter")
    <div class="footer">2013-2014</div>
@show
```

I have an error "syntax error, unexpected '/'".

The code generated by Laravel (found in app\storage\views) is wrong :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php echo $__env->yieldContent('container')
    </div>
        <?php echo $__env->make('testfooter', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Laravel forgets `;?>` after `yieldContent('container')` and adds two `;?>` after `... render()`.
I've tried many things but I really don't have any clue now.

UPDATE1
I have reinstalled a fresh Laravel and guest what, the problem is still the same. Without @include it's ok, with an @include I have the same error again and again.

UPDATE2 and **PROBLEM FIXED** (thanks to @majimboo)!
This is just unbelievable. **All that story is not related to the code. This is a problem with the text editor : Notepad++ on Windows**. For an unknown reason, and for somes files only, it switched from 'edit/EOL conversion/windows format' to 'edit/EOL conversion/Mac format'. And apparently, Laravel doesn't Mac format at all! So, if you use Notepad++ on Windows, be sure that you have : '**EOL conversion/windows format**'

Comment: To be clear, why do you have a second section for footer alone?  Since it appears `@include()` is specifying a view file, though you don't appear to be referring to that section anywhere else.(in other words, please try removing the `@section()` enclosure from the footer file(eg, leave the html content))

Comment: Even with HTML only, I have the same error.

Comment: :/ Well, I've voted this question up so hopefully it will attract the attention it needs, because I have no more ideas left.

Comment: Thanks. It's really strange. If I remove the @include, it works, if I put it back I have the same error.

Comment: @Peter I added an answer. See http://daylerees.com/codebright/blade to learn more. Search for `include`.

Comment: @Peter what IDE are you using? Is it notepad++? On what platform? Windows?

Comment: @majimboo Yes I use Notepad++ on Windows. Is it a problem ?

Comment: Although the question has been answered and fixed, I experienced a similar issue, but I found that it was because my view name had a dash in it. `view-details`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is in the file that is getting included.

First to check if the problem is really that, remove everything inside `testfooter.blade.php` then open the view from the browser. You'll notice that there is no error anymore.

Change your `testfooter.blade.php` to:

```
<div class="footer">2013-2014</div>
```

remove the `@section("testfooter")`...`@show`.

Example:

```
<!-- app/views/header.blade.php -->

<h1>When does the Narwhal bacon?</h1>

<!-- app/views/footer.blade.php -->

<small>Information provided based on research as of 3rd May '13.</small>
```

You include it like:

```
<!-- app/views/example.blade.php -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Narwhals</title>
</head>
<body>
    @include('header')
    <p>Why, the Narhwal surely bacons at midnight, my good sir!</p>
    @include('footer')
</body>
</html>
```

Check [this](http://daylerees.com/codebright/blade) to learn more on blade.

---

The problem seems to be something else, I would just like to share this, If it can help you:

> I'm using Notepad++ as text-editor and for some strange reason it had
>   decided to use "MAC format" as the End-Of-Line (EOL) format.
>   Apparently the Blade framework can't cope with that. Use the
>   conversion function (in notepad++ : Edit -> EOL Conversion) to convert
>   to Windows Format and it will work just fine...
>
> [Arjen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545086/laravel-4-blade-templates-causing-fatalerrorexception)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I've tried with `<div class="footer">2013-2014</div>` only and with nothing in `testfooter.blade.php` but the problem is still there. I've cleared my browser cache and removed the files in `storage/views`.

Comment: @Peter what code does Laravel generate now? Did it change?

Comment: Your example works. I've added `@yield('container')` and used your code as a layout and called 
`@extends("example")`
`@section('container')`
`<h1>Hello!</h1>`
`@stop`

and IT WORKS! It unbelievable! I really don't understand why the previous code didn't work.

Comment: @Peter I added some footnotes, might help. Sorry if I couldn't help any further.

Comment: @Peter But if it did help, I would also appreciate if you accept it as an answer :) good day.

Comment: Sure! Thanks! It frustrating, I still don't know why my previous code doesn't work. I don't see any difference (except the names of the files).

Comment: blade is so frustrating. i have the same kinda error. trying to solve it for 4 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
@section("testfooter")
    <div class="footer">2013-2014</div>
@show // <--
```

Change it to this:

```
@section("testfooter")
    <div class="footer">2013-2014</div>
@stop // <--
```

Comment: Damn.  I saw that as well, wasn't sure if I was right though.

Comment: Hi. I did the change, removed the files in "app\storage\views" and tried again but, unfortunately, the same error is still there.

Comment: Clear the browser cache as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was an unterminated string in some PHP in a totally different part of the file than Laravel was complaining about. I eliminated it by removing everything in the file and adding the lines in again one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Laravel gives a great hint to the problem. The problem might be in your CSS or JS include statements. First make sure you have turn on the debug mode of laravel. Here is how to do it.

1. Config/app -> debug = true at line 16
2. Refresh the page where the error is

I have intentionally leave out closing ')' of css file. The laravel FW showed where that error, and it will show you similar error.

Hope it help.